# How can I help SQL Server recognize my indexed view column is NOT NULL-able?

Tags: sql-server-2008, view, null, constraint

I have the following indexed view defined in SQL Server 2008 (you can download a working schema [from gist](https://gist.github.com/1207488) for testing purposes):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.balances
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
      user_id
    , currency_id

    , SUM(transaction_amount)   AS balance_amount
    , COUNT_BIG(*)              AS transaction_count
FROM dbo.transactions
GROUP BY
      user_id
    , currency_id
;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_balances_user_id_currency_id
ON dbo.balances (
      user_id
    , currency_id
);
GO
```

`user_id`, `currency_id`, and `transaction_amount` are all defined as `NOT NULL` columns in `dbo.transactions`. However, when I look at the view definition in Management Studio's Object Explorer, it marks both `balance_amount` and `transaction_count` as `NULL`-able columns in the view.

I've taken a look at several discussions, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326813/how-to-make-a-view-column-not-null) being the most relevant of them, that suggest some shuffling of functions may help SQL Server recognize that a view column is always `NOT NULL`. No such shuffling is possible in my case, though, since expressions on aggregate functions (e.g. an `ISNULL()` over the `SUM()`) are [not allowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921.aspx) in indexed views.

1. Is there any way I can help SQL Server recognize that `balance_amount` and `transaction_count`are `NOT NULL`-able?
2. If not, should I have any concerns about these columns being mistakenly identified as `NULL`-able?

   The two concerns I could think of are:

   - Any application objects mapped to the balances view are getting an incorrect definition of a balance.
   - In very limited cases, certain optimizations are not available to the Query Optimizer since it does not have a guarantee from the view that these two columns are `NOT NULL`.

   Is either of these concerns a big deal? Are there any other concerns I should keep in mind?

Comment: Yes there are concerns, for example your ORM will create nullable types, which in turn will need extra care in code when using them, which is useless (or even misleading) in your case.

Comment: This also appears to be an issue in a recursive cte when recursing on a non-nullable field (no aggregate) although an IsNull(..., 0) at the end can cure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `user_id`, `currency_id`, and `transaction_amount` are all defined as `NOT
>   NULL` columns in `dbo.transactions`

It looks to me that SQL Server has a blanket assumption that an aggregate can produce a `null` even if the field(s) it operates on are `not null`. This is obviously true in certain cases:

```
create table foo(bar integer not null);
select sum(bar) from foo
-- returns 1 row with `null` field
```

And is also true in the generalized versions of `group by` like [`cube`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175939(v=SQL.90).aspx)

This simpler test case illustrates the point that any aggregate is interpreted as being nullable:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.balances
with schemabinding
AS
SELECT
      user_id
    , sum(1)   AS balance_amount
FROM dbo.transactions
GROUP BY
      user_id
;
GO
```

IMO this is a limitation (albeit a minor one) of SQL Server - some other RDBMSs allow the creation of certain constraints on views that are not enforced and exist only to give clues to the optimizer, though I think 'uniqueness' is more likely to help in generating a good query plan than 'nullability'

---

If the nullability of the column is important, perhaps for use with an ORM, consider wrapping the indexed view in another view that simply guarantees the non-nullability using `ISNULL`:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.balancesORM
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT 
    B.[user_id],
    B.currency_id,
    balance_amount = ISNULL(B.balance_amount, 0),
    transaction_count = ISNULL(B.transaction_count, 0)
FROM dbo.balances AS B;
```

[image: SSMS Object Explorer Details]

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's any way you can force SQL Server to recognize these columns as not nullable, even though they clearly are not. You can try to change the order of how you define `ISNULL`/`COALESCE` around the expression *inside* `SUM()`, for example, but it's not going to help.

I also don't believe there are any optimizations you're going to miss out on - those columns aren't currently indexed, so it's not like the optimizer can choose a different access method to determine, say, all `balance_amount` values > 10000. There may be a situation where if you create a non-clustered index on one of those columns you might get slightly better estimates than if the index isn't there, but this has nothing to do with nullability.

I wouldn't be too worried about this from a performance perspective. I went back and looked at a bunch of indexed views I've created over the years and these aggregation columns are all nullable. They perform just fine.

As far as object mapping goes, again, I wouldn't be too worried about it. Since the application can't update the indexed view, it doesn't matter if it thinks that `balance_amount` can be `null`. It's never going to receive a `null`, and it can't try to write a `null`, so `<shrug>`.

Comment: Pedantic note, [[coalesce allows for nullable columns while isnull won't](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamesrowlandjones/archive/2008/07/18/isnull-lt-gt-coalesce-discuss.aspx)].

Comment: @Aaron, about object mapping: I consider it worth to look at, since a mapper will likely generate useless/misleading objects with nullable types that will never be really used as such.